# Python Modbus RTU over TCP

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I am trying to read and write data over Modbus TCP with python.
When I am using [ModbusPoll](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus_poll.html) with the following setup everything works.

[image: ModbusPoll]

I try to read the data now with python and I am using the [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for this.
My code looks like this:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer as ModbusFramer

client = ModbusTcpClient("192.168.0.7", port=502, framer=ModbusFramer)
success = client.connect()

read = client.read_holding_registers(address=4000)
read.registers
```

But I am always getting the following error:

> ModbusIOException(InvalidMessageReceivedException('No response received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)'), 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read holding register needs a unit to correctly read the message

```
read = client.read_holding_registers(address=4000, unit=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me.

Check slave_ID of your device (unit=slave_ID). It is not nessecary 1 or 0. In my case - 240, for example.

```
result = client.read_holding_registers(address=0x0010, count = 2, **unit=240**)
```

Documentation says:

```
    def write_register(self, address, value, **kwargs):
    '''

    :param address: The starting address to write to
    :param value: The value to write to the specified address
    **:param unit: The slave unit this request is targeting**
    :returns: A deferred response handle
    '''
```

And:

```
    def read_holding_registers(self, address, count=1, **kwargs):
    '''

    :param address: The starting address to read from
    :param count: The number of registers to read
    **:param unit: The slave unit this request is targeting**
    :returns: A deferred response handle
    '''
```

Look file "common.py" or press Ctrl+B while cursor is on function.