# Python Modbus RTU over TCP connect fail

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I am trying to read and write data on RTU over Modbus TCP with python.
But it prints `false`, this means `client.connect()` has failed.

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient    
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer as ModbusFramer

client = ModbusTcpClient("192.168.1.232", port=502, framer=ModbusFramer)
success = client.connect()
print(success)
```

Could anyone help to check this problem?Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're specifying the `framer`? The [example code](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#example-code) doesn't do that. Regardless, are you certain that the IP address and port are correct?

Comment: I check this link to get the info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330328/python-modbus-rtu-over-tcp, and this IP and port is correct

Comment: I want to use pymodbus to read modbus, and this modbus is RTU over TCP, so I am finding the method to read and write it

Comment: And I find the framer on this document, https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pymodbus/latest/pymodbus.pdf

Comment: If you have verified the IP address and port with different software as demonstrated in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330328/python-modbus-rtu-over-tcp), then [enable debug logging](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples.html#modbus-payload-server) and [edit] your question to include more information. To what device are you trying to connect?